# c# database read words into list

Tags: c#, database, list

I'm trying to write words from a database into a list. Now were I say 
lst.Add(reader.GetString(0));

when I'm correct, with this code you read the words from the first column into the list. Now I always get next error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I don't get it why I get the error. Anybody advice?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = D:\VisualStudio\Projects\runSheet\frontPage_V1.1\Jarvis\Jarvis\Jarvis\jarvisBrain.mdf; Integrated Security = True"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Word FROM ImportedWordList", connection))
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {  
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            lst.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
    richTextBox1.Lines = lst.ToArray();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Good time to learn how to use VS debugger....

Comment: Yes I know, I'm learning it myself, so sorry for the stupid looking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because one or more record from the table ImportedWordList contains a NULL in the column Word.

To avoid that you could change the query to

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"
           SELECT Word 
           FROM ImportedWordList 
           WHERE Word IS NOT NULL", connection))
```

In alternative you could test for null during the read:

```
 if(!reader.IsDBNull(0)
    lst.Add(reader.GetString(0));
```

Anyway it is preferable to avoid loading the null records as shown in the first example.

But this s